# Find an element using text contained in link title/subtitle

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select the link which contains medicine name ALMOGRAN, number 12.5 and 'leaflet' in the script shown below. The code I am using misses out on this element. while for other  medicine names it is working fine. What would be the best way to filter out and select this element from the webpage 
(https://products.mhra.gov.uk/search/?query=almogran&page=1)

PIL

ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETSleaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20774-1629.pdf

```
Code I am using :
elem7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'leaflet')and contains(.,'" +g+ "')]")
        link2 = elem7.get_attribute('href')
        time.sleep(15)
```

where g is the number 12.5

Please help me understand where am I going wrong I am a newbie. Thanks [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2zW2.png)

Comment: Try adding text() to them contains(text(),'leaflet')

Comment: Are you trying to click on it?

Comment: @0m3r No I want the URL for that

Comment: DO you just want this one specific link or do you want to search on text and then get the link?

Comment: XPath looks fine to me. As @Mace explained, since you use find_element you will get only one result (the first of the 4 results). What do you get with : `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'leaflet')and contains(.,'%s')]" % (g))`

Comment: I want the first result not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have finds the desired link

```
g = '12.5'
elem7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//a[contains(., 'leaflet')and contains(.,'" + g + "')]"))
print(elem7.text)
link2 = elem7.get_attribute('href')
print(link2)
```

Result

```
ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS
leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20774-1629.pdf
https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/bf115fe972a98836c2af4072a77e2aaa04bcfa24
```

But it is always the first link on the page that you'll find because you use 'find_element'. If you test your search criteria with 'find_elements' you see that it actually finds all 4 the links.

```
g = '12.5'
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//a[contains(., 'leaflet')and contains(.,'" + g + "')]"))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    link2 = element.get_attribute('href')
    print(link2)
```

Result

```
ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS
leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20774-1629.pdf
https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/bf115fe972a98836c2af4072a77e2aaa04bcfa24
ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS
leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-1099.pdf
https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/3ef1e68659b17b5cbc6bed7988dd7d32d8ff5258
ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS
leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 18799-1153.pdf
https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/91cb21381c4aea438fe87a49cfc4abd3557f7614
ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS,ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS
leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-2661.pdf
https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/f30be6ab9c3e85abd455da4262ffaf5932813014
```

So if your medicin would not have been the first on the page, your code would have found another medicin. You could make your search critera more specific. Another way is to use find_elements and add something like 'if "extra criteria" in element.text: ...' inside the for loop.

This searches for all the medicines on the page

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
def find_medicine_leaflet(page_meds, med_name):
    print(f'\n------- searching for {med_name} -------')
    nr_found = 0
    for page_med in page_meds:
        if medicine_name in page_med.text:
            nr_found += 1
            text = page_med.text.replace('\n', ' - ')
            print(f"{nr_found} {text}\n  leaflet url: {page_med.get_attribute('href')}")
    print(f'------- {nr_found} found -------\n')


# ------------------------------------------------------------------
medicine_names = [
    'ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS',
    'ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS',
    'ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS',
    'ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS,ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS',
]

g = '12.5'

page_medicines = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//a[contains(., 'leaflet')and contains(.,'" + g + "')]"))

for medicine_name in medicine_names:
    find_medicine_leaflet(page_medicines, medicine_name)
```

Result

```
------- searching for ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS -------
1 ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20774-1629.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/bf115fe972a98836c2af4072a77e2aaa04bcfa24
2 ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS,ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-2661.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/f30be6ab9c3e85abd455da4262ffaf5932813014
------- 2 found -------


------- searching for ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS -------
1 ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-1099.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/3ef1e68659b17b5cbc6bed7988dd7d32d8ff5258
2 ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 18799-1153.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/91cb21381c4aea438fe87a49cfc4abd3557f7614
------- 2 found -------


------- searching for ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS -------
1 ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-1099.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/3ef1e68659b17b5cbc6bed7988dd7d32d8ff5258
2 ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5MG TABLETS,ALMOGRAN 12.5MG TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 18799-1153.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/91cb21381c4aea438fe87a49cfc4abd3557f7614
------- 2 found -------


------- searching for ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS,ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS -------
1 ALMOGRAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS,ALMOTRIPTAN 12.5 MG FILM-COATED TABLETS - leaflet MAH BRAND_PLPI 20636-2661.pdf
  leaflet url: https://mhraproductsprod.blob.core.windows.net/docs-20200406/f30be6ab9c3e85abd455da4262ffaf5932813014
------- 1 found -------
```

As far as I can see it misses nothing. Because of the overlapping medicine names it can find 2 leaflets but everything is being found.

Comment: Sorry I had changed it back to your code variables and made a mistake. The code as it is now gives the results you see and should be ok.

Comment: Hi  @Mace this looks similar to what I have been trying and misses out on the element when I run it in a loop for multiple different medicines

Comment: The product page from your link lists 4 medicins as does the last result in my answer. It's not clear to me what you mean by ' misses out in a loop for multiple different medicines' Can you explain it? Or better, show a short working code with the loop?

Comment: I have a list of medicines and for each element in this list I am performing search on this page and extracting the first link for leaflets.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below xpath

```
g=12.5
//p[contains(text(),'leaflet') or contains(text(),'"+g+"')]//parent::a
```

or

```
g=12.5   

//a[contains(., 'leaflet') and contains(.,'"+g+"')]
```